# How to keep a media player going in mobile app?

Tags: c#, android, ios, cross-platform

So, I am looking to make a media player that is cross-platform (windows 10 + windows 10 mobile, XBOne, iOS, OSX, and Android), using C# (by far my most proficient language). I need it to remain playing in the background when the user is doing other things (for all but the XBOne). Ideally, I would like to use a cross-platform framework such as Unity, but if that's not possible, I need to know what steps I must take to make my app persist on each platform.

OSX/Windows 10 are easy, but I haven't been able to find absolutely any good information for Android/iOS especially. How does one keep a media player app going in the background on these? I see posts saying a media player that persists is doable, but they never say how.

Comment: don't look for "media player". look for "background task" or whatever. a media player is just a specific FORM of background task.

Comment: I did also do several searches for 'background task', but most of what I found was people asking about the problem, none of the info had a good answer, especially for android. Rather, there were lots of responses saying 'me too! how do I do this?'. I will search some more though in the mean time.